# Running Puppeteer on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, puppeteer

I want to run Puppeteer to scrape a web page from inside of a WKWebView on iOS. I'm wondering if this is possible and if there is a link to an existing project that does this?

Comment: Puppeteer uses Chromium and WKWebView uses Safari so I'd be surprised if there was anything that links up those two specifically

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to build a Chromium version on iOS... Longshot but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any 3rd party tool get webpage sources from WKWebView nowadays. Just use [createWebArchiveData(completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3650491-createwebarchivedata) to create Safari's *webarchive* and after that use [WebArchiveExtractor](https://robrohan.github.io/WebArchiveExtractor/) to unpack sources.